# Acces Denied in Workflows of in site collection

Tags: configuration-files, sharepoint-2013, access-denied

When I publish a workflow I receive this message "Error in configuration file".
It's happened in a specific site collection.
In site configuration I can't activate features because return access denied, but with powershell works.
Why I can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I descovery it this problem caused because i use permissions group...